# UISplitViewController's NavigationBar appear a confusing backgroundView

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

Under iOS7 SDK

1 Create a new project and use Master-Detail Application template.
2 Set `DetailViewController's background Color clear Color`.
3 Use your custom `UINavigationBar`, override `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    bounds.size.height = 88.0;
    self.bounds = bounds;
}
```

4 Run it.

Wow! what's the dark GrayColor view under the `UINavigationBar`. And, if `viewController` is `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController` and so on, relate to `scrollView`, also  a confusing offset at there.
 Anyone else know what happened?

I have not enough reputation to post an image, really frustrating！But, hope you can focus on my photo, it's the image.

Comment: What do you expect to see under the navigation bar? You made the background of the controller clear, so you're seeing through to the window, which is black.

Comment: @rdelmar I really hard to describe the problem, but when you set the custom UINavigationBar to MasterlViewController and DetailViewController's UINavigationController, the problem appears. the confusing view's frame maybe {0,0,500,108}, and has a random colour.. oh god!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Was it similar to this issue I'm having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720708/blue-sometimes-green-bar-at-top-of-uisplitviewcontroller